# What happens when I roll back an edit that was approved from the queue?

Tags: support, editing, redacting-edits

A low-rep user changed a link in one of my answers from a PDF (with warning), which contains the actual text, to the website from whence one can download the PDF. It's nice to have that link, but I prefer the citation link lead to the actual text. The edit also introduced some ugly formatting.

I plan to "fix" this edit, but since it isn't completely terrible I don't want to penalize the editor. It would be easiest for me to roll back the edit and work from there, but if I do will I remove whatever rep points the user got from the approved edit? If so, I will probably just edit over the edit.

Comment: I don't think rolling back is connected to the prior edit as a single action and so the +2 for the original edit shouldn't be affected by a roll back. Or if it really matters, instead of a rollback, just edit to what is essentially a rollback plus your extra changes (that may well involve some of the original edits).

Comment: It looks like the link you originally had would not have worked anyway (the revision history shows it started `http://file:///C:/Users/`) so to rollback would seem to me not to be a particularly good idea. I think I would prefer the link to go to the PDF if possible, but it needs to be the online offering, not on your local machine.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, I realized that when I went to edit. Fortunately, I was also able to find an online version of the appendix in question to link to, rather than just the table of contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Feel free to rollback the approved edits or improve on the existing revision.
No user will lose reputation.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up just editing again, but I'm glad to know I don't need to worry about an editor's rep if I run into a similar situation in the future.